# A question on closed convex plane curves (from Do Carmo)

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha (s)$ , $s\in [0,l]$, be a closed convex plane curve positively oriented.
The curve $\beta(s)=\alpha (s) -rn(s)$, where $r$ is a positive constant and $n(s)$ is the normal vector, is called a parallel curve to $\alpha$.
Show that:

1. $$ \text{Length}(\beta)=\text{Length}(\alpha) +2\pi r$$
2. $$ A(\beta)=A(\alpha)+rl+\pi r^2$$
3. $$k_{\beta}(s)=\frac{k_{\alpha}(s)}{1+r}$$

where the $k$'s are the curvatures of the corresponding curves.

For 1, I used the equation 
$$L(\beta)=\int_{0}^{l} \|\beta'(s)\| ds = \int_{0}^{l} (\|(1+rk_{\alpha})\alpha'(s) \| +\tau r |b(s)|) ds =L(\alpha) (1+rk)+r\tau$$

I don't see how from this I arrive at equation 1.

For 2, in this case it's the area enclosed by the curve, not sure what formulas to use here. Any hints?

For 3, I calculated according to the definition of the curvature, where $$k_{\beta}(s)=\frac{\|\gamma '(s)\|}{\|\beta '(s) \|}$$ where $\gamma (s)=\frac{\beta '(s)}{\|\beta '(s)\|}$. One of my assumptions is that we're in arclength representation, so $k_{\alpha}(s)=\|\alpha ''(s) \|$.
But I didn't arrive at the same equation, on the contrary it looks like a messy calculation that leads to nowhere.
I got that $$\gamma '(s)= \frac{r^2[r\tau ^2 k'_{\alpha}-(1+rk_{\alpha})\tau \tau ']\alpha '(s)+[(1+rk)k+r\tau ^2][(1+rk)^2+(r\tau)^2] n(s) +r\tau '(1+rk)^2 b(s)}{[(1+rk)^2+(r\tau)^2]^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
I don't see how anything gets simplified here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did $\tau$ come from? If it's supposed to be the torsion, you're aware that $\tau=0$ if $\alpha$ is flat? (Frenet-Serret simplifies vastly in the planar case, and you no longer need to consider the binormal.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**(1)** Since this is a plane curve, the torsion $\tau$ is zero. Without loss of generality we may assume $s$ is the [arclength parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Length_and_natural_parametrization) so that $\|\alpha'(s)\|=\|T\|=1$, with $T$ the tangent vector. Compute

$$\beta'=\alpha'-r(-\kappa T)=(1+r\kappa)T.$$

Above we used the [Frenet-Serret formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) to differentiate the normal vector. Hence

$$L(\beta)=\int \|\beta'\|ds=\int(1+r\kappa) ds=L(\alpha)+2\pi r.$$

Above we used the [total curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_curvature) identity $\int \kappa ds = 2\pi$.

---

**(2)** In order to compute the area of $\beta$ we will invoke [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_Calculation) in the $\mathbb{R}^3$ setting with cross products. Here $B=T\times N$ is the binormal vector - note that the cross product is antisymmetric, and the area $\tfrac{1}{2}\int xdy-ydx$ for the curve $\beta$ becomes

$$A(\beta)=\frac{1}{2}\int(\beta\times\beta')\cdot B ds$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int(\alpha-rN)\times(1+r\kappa_{\alpha})T\cdot B ds$$

Let's FOIL this into four parts:

- $\tfrac{1}{2}\int (\alpha\times T)\cdot Bds = A(\alpha)$ because $T=\alpha'$.
- $\tfrac{1}{2}\int \alpha\times (r\kappa_\alpha)T\cdot B ds=\tfrac{1}{2}r\int \alpha\times (-dN/ds)\cdot Bds$ we can rewrite using by-parts integration as $ \tfrac{1}{2}r\int T\times N\cdot Bds=\tfrac{1}{2}r L(\alpha)$.
- $\tfrac{1}{2}\int (-rN)\times T\cdot Bds=\tfrac{1}{2}r L(\alpha)$
- $\tfrac{1}{2} \int (-rN) \times (r\kappa_\alpha T)\cdot B = \pi r^2  $

Which makes a total of $A(\alpha)+rL(\alpha)+\pi r^2$.

---

**(3)** Now we'll compute $\kappa_{\beta}$ with a [local formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions_2):

$$\kappa_{\beta}=\frac{\|\beta'\times\beta''\|}{\|\beta'\|^3}=(1+r\kappa_{\alpha})^{-3}\left\|(1+r\kappa_{\alpha})T\times\left(r\frac{d\kappa_{\alpha}}{ds}T+(1+r\kappa_{\alpha})\frac{dT}{ds}\right)\right\|.$$

Note that $T\times T=0$ and $\|T \times T_s\| = \kappa_{\alpha}$ so this simplifies drastically to

$$\kappa_{\beta}=\frac{\kappa_{\alpha}}{1+r\kappa_{\alpha}}.$$

(I assume what you have written in the question is missing a $\kappa_{\alpha}$ in the denominator.)

Comment: Thanks, anon, though in question 2) you could have just tell me the first equation to use here, nontheless it was helpful. With regard to the last equation, I didn't miss it, this is how it's written in my edition of the book. I guess there's a misprint there.

Comment: in part(2) how can you get $rL(\alpha)$

Comment: @tiandiao123 $\int ds$ is length.

Comment: I mean $r\int BBds$, I am not sure how to get this, I understand the other two

Comment: @tiandiao123 $B\cdot B=1$

Comment: I am very confused as to how you derived that cross-product formula for Green's Theorem. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @FelicioGrande, I think it can be understood as follows: let $\beta(s) = (x(s),y(s),0)$, then $\beta \times \beta^{'} $ = $(0,0,x(s)y^{'}(s) - x^{'}(s)y(s))$. So $\frac{1}{2} \int_0^l\left(\beta \times \beta^{\prime}\right) \cdot B d s$ = $\frac{1}{2} \int_0^l x(s)y^{'}(s) - x^{'}(s)y(s) d s = A(\beta)$, where the last equality is Green's formula.

Comment: @anon Dear anon, I wonder in part (2): whether you missed $\left(\frac{1}{2} \int r \kappa_{\alpha} \alpha \times T \cdot B d s\right)$? Then it doesn't coincide with the right answer.

Comment: @EdwardZ.Miao Fixed.