# Enlarging an ellipses along normal direction

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given an ellipses, enlarge it along normal direction a fixed length say 1cm.
Do we get another ellipses? If so, how to prove ?

Comment: You don't usually get an ellipse: for example, consider a very long and skinny ellipse, so skinny that it looks like a line segment. Then if you enlarge it along the normal direction, you will get a shape that looks like a rectangle with semicircles stuck onto two of the edges.

Comment: I think you *never* get another ellipse except in the trivial case where the original ellipse is a circle. It's a curve of degree four. Cauchy and Cayley looked at this: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03198048

Comment: This is more difficult than I thought (deleted an answer) because the expanded ellipse may have different foci than the original.

Answer (score 7):

Bring the ellipse to  standard form 
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1,\quad a\ge b\tag1$$ The new curve is also symmetric in $x$- and $y$-axes. Its $x$-intercepts are $\pm (a+1)$, the $y$-intercepts are $\pm (b+1)$. If it were an ellipse, its equation would be 
$$\frac{x^2}{(a+1)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(b+1)^2}=1 \tag2$$
Now recall two standard facts:

1. The radii of curvature of the ellipse (1) at the vertices are $b^2/a$ and $a^2/b$. ([Source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html))
2. For a convex curve, the radius of curvature of parallel curve at outer distance $d$ is $R+d$ where $R$ is the radius for the original curve at the nearest point. This is proved  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58467/) and is geometrically evident by taking the Minkowski sum of convex set with the disk of radius $d$.

Combining 1 and 2, we conclude that 
$$
\frac{a^2}{b}+1 = \frac{(a+1)^2}{b+1} \tag3
$$
But  the difference of two sides  in (3) is $(a-b)^2/(b^2+b)$. Thus the parallel curve is an ellipse only when $a=b$.