# Enlarge a quadratic surface equally in all directions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, surfaces, quadratics

I have a quadratic surface defined by 
$$
Ax^2 + By^2 + Cy^2 + Dxy + Eyz + Fzx + Gz + Hy + Iz + J = 0
$$

I know the values of the constants $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J$.

I need to make another surface $1$ unit larger radius in all directions.

I understand the $G$, $H$ and $I$ are the centre of the quadratic surface and the $J$ relates to the radius.

So all I want to do is find a new value of $J$ that produces a new surface slightly ($1$ unit) larger than the old one with the same orientation and centre point.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you start with a Sphere: $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 = 0$ ? Also, what units are you starting with?

Comment: It is not actually true that $G, H, I$ ARE the centre of the surface, but they can be used, together with the values of $A, B, C$ to find the centre. You actually need to do some completing-the-square things to find the centre.

Comment: Once the center is located as Old John suggests, via completing the squares, maybe what you want is to set up a coordinate system there, and subject the curve to a homothety. However I can't see in general a way to make the new conic "one unit larger" whatever that means. For example an ellipse which is moved outward by a constant amount in the normal direction is no longer an ellipse, or even a conic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The planar version of this question is [Enlarging an ellipses along normal direction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/429110/). As you can see there, an enlarged ellipse is not an ellipse or any quadric curve, unless the original ellipse was a circle. Rotating an ellipse around its axis, we conclude that for ellipsoids of revolution (at least) the result of enlargement is not an ellipsoid.

Thus, there is no $J$ that will do the job. You can obtain a parametric form of the enlarged surface by beginning with a parametrization $\vec r(u,v)$ of the ellipdoid and calculating 
$$\vec r  + \frac{\vec r_u \times \vec r_v}{|\vec r_u \times \vec r_v|} \tag{1}$$ 
(Or with $-$ instead of $+$, if the cross product points inside). You will quickly find that (1) is not a pretty formula to look at.